# Как использовать Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, typescript, angular-cli

Не уверен, что правильно поставлен вопрос но постараюсь объяснить в деталях.

Есть небольшой готовый проект на **Angular**(последняя версия на **TypeScript**) работает как надо на локальном сервере. Возможно ли этот проект запустить без сервера? То есть как в первом **Angular** просто добавить ссылки **CDN** или есть еще какие то варианты или нужен только сервер? Спасибо за ответ за ранее.

Comment: все зависит от кода, если ты на сервере ничего не делаешь, то делаешь build в системе сборки, которую используешь и полученные файлы просто добавляешь на CDN

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю в какую сторону копать.

Comment: По мне самый простой способ, это запустить локальный сервер İİS и на нем поднять сайт...
Есть вариант с публикацией на github и firebase

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете Angular CLI, то он использует сервер в целях сборки проекта и пересборки при выявлении изменений в файлах. Если вы используете команду ng build, то получите папку dist с сжатыми файлами вашего проекта (это статика, но работать без сервера не будет).

Можно использовать загрузчик System.js с CDN, к примеру с unpkg.com, на Plunker есть шаблоны. Но этот вариант только для мелких черновиков, для продакшена Angular CLI или кастомные сборки на базе webpack или rollup.

Comment: (это статика, но работать без сервера не будет) -- А почему не будет?

Comment: Из-за <base href="/"> который необходим для Angular. <base href="/"> это база для всех ссылок в проекте. 


Если убрать то Angular бросит ошибку - `No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.`

C базой путь к файлу - `/polyfills.bundle.js`
Без базы - `file:///Users/username/Desktop/angular2-form-validation/dist/polyfills.bundle.js`

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема добавить это в html? Или ангуляр не сможет работать если js подгружены с домена отличного от того с которого index.html загружен? Даже если все js включены в index.html?

Comment: В том то и проблема что если вы работаете без сервера у вас нет домена. Angular-у нужен window.location.origin для работы роутера, который без домена равен null. Можете попробовать вставить в базу путь к вашей папке со статикой, будет ошибка.